# How to tell what is wrong in the network dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network, closest-facility

I work in ArcGIS 10.3. I have a network dataset consisting of lines and points. When I run the closest facility in Network Analyst, it works perfectly everywhere but on this particular edge/part of the network. If I solve the two points, the route it creates goes around the area, not the shortest path as it should.
What could be wrong? I checked if there is no gap between vertices.

I read something about Verify and repair connectivity tool but it requires Network Geometry Dataset. Is there a way to fix my network so the shortest routes are found correctly?
Watch the picture bellow for detailed view.

[image: My network and created route]

[image: Vertices]

Comment: There's a missing node where best route sharply turns North.

Comment: A missing node? How can I tell? How do I repair it so it goes south? Thank you a lot.

Comment: Split long line at this corner and snap the end of short one to split point.

Comment: The highlighted line isn't one line but consists of many lines (edges), therefore I couldnt split it at the corner because two lines ends there. I tried to snap the short line to the junction but with no avail to the shortest route problem. The route still creates on the longer run.

I edited the polylines and made sure they snapped. Created new network dataset from them and tried closest facility. Still broken.

Comment: Also, when I disconnect the "northern" road so that only "south" way exists, the route solve gives me no result saying "no solution find". But what could be wrong? It doesn't seem disconnected or anything.

Comment: Furthermore, I created new features (two points) in the point layer that I load locations from and now the points connected correctly. What could be wrong with my other points? If I try routing them, it won't find a path. The points are towns, lines are roads.The road is connected, towns seem to appear lying on the roads. Where could be the problem?

Comment: Something wrong with short line. Possibly multiparts? Try to redraw it or simply replace with straight segment.

Comment: I uploaded a picture of vertices of that short line. Isn't there a problem if the last added vertice (the red one) is in the middle? I didn't create the road network layer. I can't really redraw it because it's a real, existing road. But no other way to fix it I guess.

Comment: I managed to redraw the short line following the vertices and now it routes correctly. Finally! I don't know who created the roads layer but he didn't do a good job. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried passing your data through repair geometry tool? I've seen this sort of problem in River Networks and I'm sure have used repair geometry to fix it.